# PowerShell sessions not going away

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a simple script to do iterate over an array of hosts and run a command remotely.

```
$myHost = @("hostA")
$command = { hostname }
foreach ($i in $myHost) {
  Write-Host $i
  $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $i -Credential $cred
  $res = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $command
  if ($?) {
    $res 
  }
  Remove-PSSession -Session $session
}
```

I can still see the session alive when I do `Get-PSSession`.

Comment: Does the remote session _eventually_ go away, or does it persist for however long your current session remains open? What PS version and platform?

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak a little bit. Sometimes Powershell hold the Invoked runspace as session.

```
$myHost = @("localhost")
$command = { hostname }
foreach ($i in $myHost) {
  Write-Host $i
  $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $i -Credential $cred
  $res = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $command
  if ($?) {
    $res 
  }
# Get all the sessions and remove at once.
  Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession 
}
```

Hope it helps